# identify the localhost IP address

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I wanted ti install opendaylight as a container in Docker using Ubuntu 20 following the steps in this website
https://hub.docker.com/r/glefevre/opendaylight

in this step
Access Opendaylight karaf CLI

`ssh -p 8101 karaf@localhost Default password is "karaf"`

how can I know the localhost IP address? is it docker IP address?

Comment: Localhost address is always the same on all operating systems. It's 127.0.0.1. Localhost is just a more friendly name.

Comment: Why you need IP address there? Just leave as it is - localhost.

Comment: Do you mean the external host address? `localhost` (127.0.0.1) is something complete internal to any machine, not accessible outside the host.

Comment: @GintsGints you mean I shouldnt change it to IP address?

Comment: Yes you should not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is not docker address. In example, it is meant to be host system address. You can use your host system address, because docker port is mapped with command above, which contains port mapping from docker to your hosting machine - `-p 8181:8181`

Comment: I put 127.0.0.1 instead of "localhost" and it worked but when I turned the machine power off it gives me "ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 8101:connection refused" I have to repeat the whole steps everyday to make it works again

Comment: Docker stops all it's containers when you shutdown your machine. You can check your running containers status with command: ```docker ps```. You will see started container and it's name. You can use that name to stop that container before shutdown by ```docker stop <container_name>``` and then start it again with ```docker start <container_name>```.

Or you can use this manual - https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/ to make your containers recreate on reboot.